# How to override printing in python multiprocessing

Tags: python, io, output, python-multiprocessing, python-multithreading

I have a class AlternativePrinter that overrides the python print function (in this example it appends "[write to terminal]" before outputs) but for some reason anything printed from within a multiprocessing process doesn't go through this print function. How can I make all printing including from processes go through my new printer?

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import sys
import time

class AlternativePrinter:
    def __init__(self):
        self.old_stdout = sys.stdout
        sys.stdout = self

    # executed when the user does a `print`
    def write(self, text):
        self.old_stdout.write("\n[write to terminal]"+text)

    def __enter__(self):
        return self

    def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
        sys.stdout = self.old_stdout

    def flush(self):
        self.old_stdout.flush()

def wait_and_print(seconds):
    time.sleep(seconds)
    print("I waited for", seconds, "seconds")
    return seconds

if __name__ == "__main__":
    with AlternativePrinter():
        print('Initiating simultaneous processes:')
        pool = mp.Pool(4)
        input = [(4,),(2,)]
        results = pool.starmap(wait_and_print, input)
        pool.close()
        pool.join()
        for result in results:
            print(result)
```

output:

```
[write to terminal]Initiating simultaneous processes:
[write to terminal]
I waited for 2 seconds
I waited for 4 seconds

[write to terminal]4
[write to terminal]

[write to terminal]2
[write to terminal]
```

end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `with AlternativePrinter():` in `wait_and_print`. The lines below `if __name__ == "__main__":` are not executed in the child process and hence AlternativePrinter() is never used.